# Soap4r : the requested address is not valid in the its context

Tags: ruby, httpclient, soap4r, wsdl2ruby

I was wondering if somebody has seen this error before?

> C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.1.5.2/lib/httpclient/session.rb:675:in `initialize': The requested address is not valid in its context. - connect(2) (://:0) (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)

```
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.1.5.2/lib/httpclient/session.rb:675:in `new'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.1.5.2/lib/httpclient/session.rb:675:in `create_socket'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.1.5.2/lib/httpclient/session.rb:632:in `connect'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.1.5.2/lib/httpclient/timeout.rb:128:in `timeout'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.1.5.2/lib/httpclient/session.rb:631:in `connect'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.1.5.2/lib/httpclient/session.rb:522:in `query'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.1.5.2/lib/httpclient/session.rb:147:in `query'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.1.5.2/lib/httpclient.rb:953:in `do_get_block'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.1.5.2/lib/httpclient.rb:765:in `do_request'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.1.5.2/lib/httpclient.rb:848:in `protect_keep_alive_disconnected'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.1.5.2/lib/httpclient.rb:764:in `do_request'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.1.5.2/lib/httpclient.rb:666:in `request'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.1.5.2/lib/httpclient.rb:596:in `post'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/streamHandler.rb:238:in `send_post'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/streamHandler.rb:172:in `send'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/proxy.rb:179:in `route'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/proxy.rb:143:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/driver.rb:181:in `call'
    from (eval):6:in `preRepairAuthorizationQA'
    from C:/documents and settings/ngorbikoff/Desktop/GMW/WSDL/ProcessMessageClient.rb:21
```

I'm trying to connect to a service, I just generated this soap client from wsdl2ruby. Everything went fine. So I have no idea why this error is happening. This is a fresh install of ruby 1.8.7 on Windows, but I tested this on another Windows machine with Ruby 1.8.6 and on a Debian server with REE 1.8.7  - same error. My gut feeling is that it has to do with the httpclient  lib - but I can't find anything on google - regarding this err, other than some references to Pythong and tcl - which seem to be unrelated. Also I'm trying to connect to wsdl service that is on httpS - but I didn't have this problem before and there were no changes on the server.

Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK nevermind people. For anyone else looking into this cryptic message if you are using wsdl2ruby - make sure that you define your endpoint_url in the WhateverServiceClient.rb file generated by the wsdl3ruby.